# On page back form options are mismatched

Tags: javascript, jquery

Cobbled together a form where the choice from the first dropdown menu effects what options are shown in a second dropdown.

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#sashcolour').on('change', function() {
  if($(this).val() === "Emerald"||
     $(this).val() === "Hot Pink"||
     $(this).val() === "Red")
  {
    $("#printall").show().prop('disabled', false);
  }
  else
  {
    $("#printall").hide().prop('disabled', true);
  }
  if($(this).val() === "White"||
     $(this).val() === "Baby Pink"||
     $(this).val() === "Baby Blue")
  {
    $("#printlight").show().prop('disabled', false);
  }
  else
  {
    $("#printlight").hide().prop('disabled', true);
  }
  if($(this).val() === "Black"||
     $(this).val() === "Royal Blue"||
     $(this).val() === "Purple")
  {
    $("#printdark").show().prop('disabled', false);
  }
  else
  {
    $("#printdark").hide().prop('disabled', true);
  }
});
```

});

http://jsfiddle.net/zttjqw6g/

My problem is if the form is submitted and then the user goes back via the browser back button the first dropdown stays on the item opened but the second reverts to the default. eg dropdown 1 - user selects "black" and sees the following options in dropdown 2 - "white", "gold", "silver".
but... when the form is submitted and the user presses the back button dropdown 1 shows "black" but dropdown 2 shows "black", "gold", "silver" the first option list.

I've very limited knowledge and just can't see what I'm doing wrong. Any help gratefully received!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JS needs to execute on page load to retrieve the right value. To do this, trigger the change by adding `.change()` after your event listener:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#sashcolour').on('change', function(){
        /* ... */
    }).change();
});
```

Comment: Worked a charm! Thank you blex.